# VSCode: How to remove git decorator information from file tabs?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Since today, I have git information in the file tabs, probably since the last update. I want to remove that information, because I find it too heavy.

I do not find where in the settings it is. Do someone here knows ?
VSCode version: 1.55.0

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off the `git > decorations` setting.
[image]
You can also add the following line in `settings.json`

```json
"git.decorations.enabled": false
```

Comment: This does remove the tab decorations but **also** removes them from the Explorer which may not be desired.  See the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 10):

This is called Tab decoration, the corresponding settings are called:

`workbench.editor.decorations`

`workbench.editor.decorations.badges`

[image: settings window screenshot]

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/cd717bb4195d40ae8f556679348d38d6dce4321a/release-notes/v1_53.md#tab-decorations

Comment: Thanks guys, you are wonderful!